# Get an object of multiple person first and last name comma separeted

Tags: javascript

So in my JS I have 3 variables like so;

```
fName = 'Lili, Abraham';
lName = 'Vabiens, Lincoln';
email = 'l@vbiens.com, a@lcln.com'
```

And I'd like to get an object of the person details like so.

So, in the end, I'd have this:

```
{ firstName: "Lily", lastName: "Vabiens", fullName: : "Lily Vabiens", email: "l@vbiens.com" },
{ firstName: "Abraham", lastName: "Lincoln", fullName: : "Abraham Lincoln", email: "a@lcln.com" },
```

What would be the smartest way of going about this?

Comment: Did you try anything? -- You should split the variables by the comas and then use a loop to create the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Now considering the lengths of each attribute of data is same, the following code will work.

First we split the strings into arrays.

```
fName = 'Lili, Abraham';
lName = 'Vabiens, Lincoln';
email = 'l@vbiens.com, a@lcln.com'

f_name_list = fName.split(', ');
l_name_list = lName.split(', ');
email_list = email.split(', ');
```

Then we loop and append an object to an array.

```
let result = [];

for ( let i = 0; i < f_name_list.length; i++ ) {
  result.push({
    firstName: f_name_list[i],
    lastName: l_name_list[i],
    fullName: f_name_list[i] + ' ' + l_name_list[i],
    email: email_list[i]
  });
}
```